# UWSim Pressure Sensor Units

Tags: ros, simulation, underwater

I am attempting to use the data Underwater Simulator (UWSim) provides through the ROS interface to simulate a number of sensors that will be running on a physical aquatic robot. One of the sensors detects the current depth of the robot so, I want to simulate this with the data provided by the UWSim simulated pressure sensor. The Problem is that nowhere in the UWSim wiki or source code can I find any reference to what units UWSim uses to measure pressure.

That being said, what units does UWSim use to measure pressure? Additionally, I would appreciate general information about what units UWSim uses for the data provided by it's virtual sensors.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ROS before, but you could try to determine the pressure units with an experiment!

1. Put your sensor in water and take a pressure measurement.
2. Lower the sensor 10.3 meters, or about 34 feet, and take another pressure measurement.
3. Subtract (1) from (2), and look for the correct "ballpark":

   - ~1 = bar
   - ~14.7 = psi
   - ~101 = kPa
   - ~1,000 = mbar
   - ~101,000 = Pa

This test checks the change in pressure when changing depth to a pressure difference of [1 atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure).